# PostgreSQL Trigger with duplicate values

Tags: sql, function, postgresql, triggers

I'm very new in SQL and PostgreSQl, and I need a desperate answer for the following question:

I have the next two tables with the following information:

MATCH_STATISTICS

[image]

MATCH

[image]

With these two tables I need make a TRIGGER wich adds the player from MATCH_STATISTICS to MATCH with the MAX value from 'mvp_score'.

In other words, I want to add the most valuable player from MATCH_STATISTICS to MATCH but with one condition:
* If there are two players with the same mvp_score, the most valuable player stored will be that one with the MAX minutes played.

I am capable to do the first TRIGGER with the max value but when I have two duplicate values the code adds the last modified.

Anyone knows how to do that? The TRIGGER should act after INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE

Thanks so much and sorry for my bad english...

Comment: Why do you want to use a trigger for this?  This is easy enough to calculate with a query.  And, unless your tables have hundreds of thousands of rows or more, you probably won't even notice the performance.

Comment: Because I need to UPDATE the table with new information using INSERTS and UPDATES. I don't want to UPDATE manually MATCH table. In other words I want a TRIGGER to control the most valuable player after I added new lines in MATCH_STATISTICS.

Comment: No you don't need to UPDATE the match table. Create a **view** that returns that information instead. Then you don't need to worry about a trigger.

Comment: I'm absolutely agree with you but I need to solve this problem with a TRIGGER. Doesn't matter if there are better solutions, in my case I need a TRIGGER. I'm sorry but that's the deal.

Comment: Ok well... then how can I do that view or query? Because I have no idea how to do it...

Comment: See here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/d1b91/1

Comment: Thanks so much! Finally I got an answer thanks to this website and a TRIGGER solution for that. I'll post soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a way to make a TRIGGER wich solves my problem, the code is...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION mvp_player_equal()
RETURNS trigger AS $$
DECLARE
    max_points INTEGER;
BEGIN
    SELECT MAX(mvp_score)
    INTO max_points
    FROM MATCH_STATISTICS;

    IF (TG_OP = 'INSERT') THEN

        IF max_points = NEW.mvp_score THEN 
            UPDATE match SET mvp_player = (SELECT player FROM MATCH_STATISTICS WHERE minutes_played = 
            (SELECT MAX(minutes_played) FROM MATCH_STATISTICS WHERE mvp_score = NEW.mvp_score) 
                AND mvp_score = NEW.mvp_score) WHERE home_team = NEW.home_team AND visitor_team = NEW.visitor_team;
        END IF;

        RETURN NULL;

    ELSIF (TG_OP = 'UPDATE') THEN

        IF max_points = NEW.mvp_score THEN 
                UPDATE match SET mvp_player = (SELECT player FROM MATCH_STATISTICS WHERE minutes_played = 
                (SELECT MAX(minutes_played) FROM MATCH_STATISTICS WHERE mvp_score = NEW.mvp_score) 
                AND mvp_score = NEW.mvp_score) WHERE home_team = NEW.home_team AND visitor_team = NEW.visitor_team;

        END IF;

        RETURN NULL;

    END IF; 

END;
$$LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER mvp_player_equal AFTER INSERT OR DELETE OR UPDATE OF
mvp_score ON MATCH_STATISTICS
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE mvp_player_equal();
```

But as in the previous comments is talked, that's not the better way to fix this issue. There are better ways like [Gordon Linoff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1144035/gordon-linoff) and [a_horse_with_no_name](https://stackoverflow.com/users/330315/a-horse-with-no-name) said.